# How to retrieve text from table cell using Jquery dynamically

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I have a requirement where I need to get the data "Reservation 1" and "Reservation 2" in the below mentioned HTML by using Jquery

Also the below mentioned "input class="top Left" value=" 8 "" is dynamic so, every time I am querying we need to pass the value dynamically the value like 8,9,10 etc....

Reservation 1

---

Reservation 2

---

Comment: You need to at least add the actual HTML code to your question if you want help. Also it's a good idea to show the efforts you have put into solving the problem your self.

Comment: do u want the text of the td in the tr of passed value in the table right .or else something.if possible highlight need in more clear

Answer (score 0):

```
var txt = $("table >tr:eq("+value+") >td>div").html();
```

Comment: Thank you John. I need to query the text which is inside div tags. The div's are inside table, tr and td which dont have any ID's. Div has title  like title="Click to Edit reservation".Please guide me

Comment: like table tr td and td contains the div with text and you want that text right based on the number you pass like 4 means it has to get the text reservation4 right

Comment: i have just edited the code have a look @RajendraGundimeda

Comment: There are multiple Div tags in the code which are being created dynamically so, I have written code as below<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var d = new Date();
     var day = d.getDate();
     alert(day);
     $("input[type='button']").each(function() 
      {
            var text1 = $("input[type='button']").val();
             alert(text1)
            if(text1 == day)
           {
            var text = $(".idiv").text();
            
           }
        });
});
</script> Every time I query the child div tags I am getting same value, the value is repeating that's the issue